# Saving multiple image paths while inserting data in 2 tables in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I am trying to make this app work. At the moment it does upload multiple images to '[upload]' folder and data in one of the table (other than image folder).

I have 2 tables. One for other info and one images only. Other info table inserts even if there is an error. while image table doesn't insert anything.

My model is:

```
function insert_property_details($data) {
$this->db->trans_start();
// First Table
       $insert_property_in_database=array(
       'v_item_title'   => $this->input->post('v_item_title'),
       'v_item_description' => $this->input->post('v_item_description'),
       'images_reference_id'    => $this->db->insert_id(),
       );
       $query=$this->db->insert('vbc_vacation_item_attri',$insert_property_in_database);
        return $query;
// Second Table
        $data = array('property_images' => $data['uploadedimage']);
        $this->db->insert('vbc_property_images', $data);

        $this->db->trans_complete();
        return $this->db->insert_id();
}
```

Upload controller:

```
  $this->upload->initialize($config);
  if ($this->upload->do_upload('uploadedimage')) {
    $data['upload_data'] = $this->upload->data();
    $image_name = $data['upload_data']['file_name'];

    $data['upload_data'] = $image_name;
    $this->load->model('admin/model_users');
    $this->model_users->insert_property_details($data);
  } else {
```

Controller that links to FORM:

```
public function post_property() {
//Some validation code here
if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
        redirect('dashboard/add-new-listing');
} else {
        $this->load->model('admin/model_users');
        if($query = $this->model_users->insert_property_details()) {
        redirect('dashboard/property-successfully-posted');
   }
}
```

And the FORM:

```
<input type="file" class="input-text-custom" data-placeholder="select image/s" name="uploadedimages[]" accept="image/*" multiple id="file" />
```

Please Help.

Answer (score 0):

In your model there is a `return` statement given -

```
return $query;
```

So the remaining codes won't execute, that's why images related data is not inserting

```
 function insert_property_details($data) {
$this->db->trans_start();
// First Table
       $insert_property_in_database=array(
       'v_item_title'   => $this->input->post('v_item_title'),
       'v_item_description' => $this->input->post('v_item_description'),
       'images_reference_id'    => $this->db->insert_id(),
       );
       $query=$this->db->insert('vbc_vacation_item_attri',$insert_property_in_database);
       // return $query;  this is not required
// Second Table
        $data = array('property_images' => $data['uploadedimage']);
        $this->db->insert('vbc_property_images', $data);

        $this->db->trans_complete();
        return $this->db->insert_id();
}
```

Comment: thanks... I tried that.. I says 'Missing argument 1 for model_users::insert_property_details(), called in'.. Thats in model

Comment: can you please chack the $data in coming in side model function by doing a print_r($data) in  function insert_property_details($data) {

Comment: By doing print_r($data) in function insert_property_details($data), it show array of all images selected... But at the same error also with 1 more with "Message: Undefined variable: data at line 178" which is `"property_images" => $data['uploadedimage'],`

Comment: Also... When I check my property image table.. Is that normal that each image is in separate row... or all images should be in same row?

Comment: better way will be looping the image post array and passing individual entries to upload function.